# Where to permit a parameter in a has_one/belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When I try and edit the Contact to add a DataType, I receive a: 'Unpermitted parameter: data_format' error. I have tried following similar associations I have found online, but can't figure out what I am missing. I apologize if this is redundant.

Here are the relevant pieces of information:

**Models:**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: contacts
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  name        :string
#  email       :string
#  phone       :string
#  mobile      :string
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#  supplier_id :integer
#
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :data_type
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :data_type, allow_destroy: true
end
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: data_formats
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  contact_id :integer
#
class DataFormat < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :contact
end
```

**Contact Controller:**

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_contact, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save
        format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contact }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def set_contact
      @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    end

    def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :mobile, :data_format,
                                      data_format_attributes: [ :id, :name, :contact_id, :_destroy ] )
    end
end
```

**Edit View:**

```
<%= simple_form_for @contact do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <%= f.input :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :data_format do |t| %>
        <%= t.input :id, label: 'Date Format:', :collection => DataFormat.order(:name) %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <%= f.label "Submit", class: 'control-label' %>
      <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The DataType(s) are appearing in the form and I can select them. So, I know the issue must be within the controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `contact.rb` is accepting nested attributes name and `permitted parameters` name mismatch. `contact.rb` mentions: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :data_type, allow_destroy: true .`

**contact.rb**

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :data_format
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :data_format, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**contacts_controller.rb**

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_contact, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
    @contact.data_format = DataFormat.new
  end

  ...

    private

        def set_contact
          @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
        end

        def contact_params
          params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :mobile, :data_format,
                                          data_format_attributes: [ :id, :name, :contact_id, :_destroy ] )
        end
```

**form**

```
<%= simple_form_for @contact do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <%= f.input :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :data_format, @contact.data_format do |t|%>
        <%= t.input :id, label: 'Date Format:', :collection => DataFormat.order(:name) %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <%= f.label "Submit", class: 'control-label' %>
      <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the reply! After making those corrections, my input field disappeared. Any suggestions?

Comment: You also need to ```build``` inside the ```new``` action, in order to have a instance of the object for the form to load from. I have update the answer. See if that helps.

Comment: Hey! I just stumbled across that as well. However, the input still isn't showing up.

Comment: If I change :data_format -> :data_formats in the simple_form, the field comes up again, but then I run into the unpermitted parameter issue again.

Comment: ```has_one``` should have the assoc singular. I updated the answer with the revised form to build the form fields for ```data_format``` using ```@contact```'s built up ```data_format``` instance. See if that works.

Comment: Unfortunately, still having problems with that input field appearing :-/

Comment: I have updated the controller code for new action. Using ```@contact.data_format = DataFormat.new```. Try now.

Comment: No difference with that change.

Comment: try reverting the form to the original version and keep the new changes in the controller.

Comment: Thank you for your continued help! No luck with reverting the form back to the original though. Still coming up blank.

Comment: hm. Not sure. Just to be sure, see you are not using ```data_type``` anywhere. And only ```data_format```. I will update the answer if I think of anything else.

Comment: Also try a different ```input``` or ```text_field```. Like ```name``` and see if that appears.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to accept this as the correct answer because it did solve my initial problem. I really appreciate your time and effort!

Comment: Sure. Also check to see that its a fresh request to the ```new``` action and not a failed  ```render``` response of the ```new``` action from ```create```. You should also account for the ```build``` or similar, in the rendering of the ```new``` action in your ```create``` action.